# How to customize list preference radio button

Tags: android, radio-button, customization, listpreference

I have customized all the radioButtons in my application but the radioButtons in the listPreference does not get customized.

I have used this xml named btn_radio.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true" android:state_window_focused="false"
      android:drawable="@drawable/radio_selected" />
<item android:state_checked="false" android:state_window_focused="false"
      android:drawable="@drawable/radio_unselected" />

<item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/radio_selected" />
<item android:state_checked="false" android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/radio_unselected" />

<item android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/radio_selected" />
<item android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/radio_unselected" />

<item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/radio_unselected" />
<item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/radio_selected" />
</selector>
```

This is the customRadioButton which extends the android custom radio button

```xml
<style name="CustomRadioButton"    Parent="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
    <item name="android:button">@drawable/btn_radio</item>
</style>
```

in the theme of my application I have done this changes

```
<item name="android:radioButtonStyle">@style/CustomRadioButton</item>
    <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorSingle">@style/CustomRadioButton</item>
```

**This changes customize all the radioButtons in my application except radioButtons in my ListPreference**

Answer (score 30):

Styling the `ListPreference` from XML is not directly possible. The problem is that `ListPreference` (through `DialogPreference`) calls `AlertDialog.Builder(Context)` to build its `Dialog`, rather than `AlertDialog.Builder(Context context, int themeResourceId)`. While the latter allows for providing a theme, the former does not, causing it to fall back to a default Android theme.

For a project, I needed a `ListPreference` with a custom title-color, a custom radiobutton-style and a custom ListView-selector (basically, Holo in a different color). I solved this by extending `ListPreference` and overriding `onPrepareDialogBuilder(Builder)` and `OnCreateDialogView()` so I could use a custom ListView with a simple ArrayAdapter, rather than `Dialog`'s built-in `ListView` (which doesn't have support for styling). I also had to override `onDialogClosed()` in order to set the right value to the preference.

In order to use it, all you have to do is replace the classname of the preference in your preferences.xml rom `ListPreference` to `com.your.packagename.ThemedListPreference`. Other than that, the implementation is identical to ListPreference.

```
public class ThemedListPreference extends ListPreference implements OnItemClickListener {

    public static final String TAG = "ThemedListPreference";

    private int mClickedDialogEntryIndex;

    private CharSequence mDialogTitle;

    public ThemedListPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ThemedListPreference(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected View onCreateDialogView() {
        // inflate custom layout with custom title & listview
        View view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.dialog_settings_updatetime, null);

        mDialogTitle = getDialogTitle();
        if(mDialogTitle == null) mDialogTitle = getTitle();
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_title)).setText(mDialogTitle);

        ListView list = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        // note the layout we're providing for the ListView entries
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(
                getContext(), R.layout.btn_radio,
                getEntries());

        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        list.setItemChecked(findIndexOfValue(getValue()), true);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPrepareDialogBuilder(Builder builder) {
        // adapted from ListPreference
        if (getEntries() == null || getEntryValues() == null) {
            // throws exception
            super.onPrepareDialogBuilder(builder);
            return;
        }

        mClickedDialogEntryIndex = findIndexOfValue(getValue());

        // .setTitle(null) to prevent default (blue)
        // title+divider from showing up
        builder.setTitle(null);

        builder.setPositiveButton(null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        mClickedDialogEntryIndex = position;
        ThemedListPreference.this.onClick(getDialog(), DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        getDialog().dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
            // adapted from ListPreference
        super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);

        if (positiveResult && mClickedDialogEntryIndex >= 0
                && getEntryValues() != null) {
            String value = getEntryValues()[mClickedDialogEntryIndex]
                    .toString();
            if (callChangeListener(value)) {
                setValue(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For my ListView items I used the layout below. Note that drawable/btn_radio_holo_light is an XML-drawable like the one in your android-sdk/platforms/android-x/data/res/drawable folder, only with references to different drawables.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checkMark="@drawable/btn_radio_holo_light"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/list_item_minheight"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_item_paddingLeft"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_item_paddingLeft" />
```

For my Dialog layout (`onCreateDialogView()`), I used the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:textColor="@color/title_color"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@color/divider_color" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what is `CheckedTextView` here,is it any custom view created. Could you please guide.

Comment: what should be in this `R.layout.btn_radio` layout.

Comment: @NidhiGondhia, [CheckedTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckedTextView.html) is a standard Android widget.  The code snippet that starts with `<CheckedTextView...` is what should be in `R.layout.btn_radio`.  Instead of `btn_radio` a better name might be `list_item`.

Comment: Thanks. I was searching for hours to get a proper workaround. This solution is the best I have ever seen.
This question should be voted as "checked" :)

Comment: I thnk it no longer works. Can't override 'onCreateDialogView'. Using PreferenceFragmentCompat.

Answer (score 0):

Please, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66336811/11004423), maybe it helps.

It's a much easier way to solve the problem.