# android: How to change ListPreference title colour?

Tags: android, styles, android-preferences

I would like to change the title and line color of my ListPreference from blue to pink, to match the line of my action bar.

[image: ListPreference]

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

I've been looking through Android's `themes.xml` and `styles.xml` looking at things like `dialogPreferenceStyle`, but haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Had the same problem today.
Old thread, but I found [this:](http://news.ebscer.com/2015/06/theming-listpreference-dialogs-on-android-lollipop/) and it works perfectly.

Simply modify your styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <!-- Add this -->

    <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/DialogStyle</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/DialogStyle</item>

</style>

<!-- Customize your color here -->

<style name="DialogStyle" parent="android:Theme.Material.Dialog">
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Nice, way cleaner solution!

Comment: I'm always at a complete lost when it comes to messing around with `styles.xml`, after hours of digging through answers this is the one that lead me on the right path.

Answer (score 2):

Ended up creating a custom `ListPreference` widget, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14790665/1438809).

I hoped to be able to simply change the style without having to implement a custom widget, but I haven't figured that out yet.

Comment: Did you get it? I want to change the background color

Comment: @BhargavKumarR Unfortunately I didn't figure out a way without creating a custom widget following the linked answer.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I spent enough time to do it with some kind of style attributes but could not. I will try your solution and +1 :)

Comment: Bhargav Kumar R, maybe this? item name="android:windowBackground">@color/somecolor</item>