# ListPreference text color

Tags: android, android-preferences

I'm having a hard time trying to style a ListPreference.

I've applied a main theme which declares a preferenceTheme and both of them link to a dialogTheme (and alertDialogTheme respectively). It works except that the text color of the items doesn't change - but the color of all other texts does. I cannot rely on a workaround because I'm using the v7 preferences and thus cannot override the dialog methods in a custom class.
For me it looks like the rows ignore the text color value, but maybe someone else has a solution for this. Otherwise this might be a bug?

Main style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- [...] -->        
    <!-- Some color values -->

    <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/DialogTheme</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/DialogTheme</item>
    <item name="dialogTheme">@style/DialogTheme</item>
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/DialogTheme</item>
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceTheme</item>

</style>
```

PreferenceTheme:

```
<style name="PreferenceTheme" parent="PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material">
    <!-- [...] -->
    <!-- Some color values -->
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/preference_primary_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/preference_primary_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/preference_primary_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/preference_primary_color</item>
    <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/preference_primary_color</item>

    <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/DialogTheme</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/DialogTheme</item>
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceTheme</item>
</style>
```

DialogTheme:

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:textColor">#EEEEEE</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#EEEEEE</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#EEEEEE</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">#EEEEEE</item>
    <item name="android:textColorTertiary">#EEEEEE</item>
    <item name="android:textColorAlertDialogListItem">#EEEEEE</item>
    <item name="android:editTextColor">#EEEEEE</item>

    <item name="color">#EEEEEE</item>
</style>
```

[image: This is how it looks.] 

This is how it looks.The text should be `#EEEEEE`. I've snipped it but the text colors are applied in each of the given styles.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You did everything right, except one thing: do not use the `android` prefix when overriding `textColorAlertDialogListItem` because this is not the framework version of `AlertDialog`.

This statement is generally true for almost all attributes that belong to the support widgets / views. The reason is pretty straightforward: not all attributes are available on the older platforms. Such example is `android:colorControlActivated` which was introduced in API 21. The AppCompat lib declares its own `colorControlActivated` so it's available on older API levels, too. In this case the developer should not use the `android` prefix when defining the style in the theme as that would point to the platform version of the attribute instead of the AppCompat one.

**TL;DR:** Do not use the `android` prefix for support widgets unless you have to (i.e. you get compilation error).

---

P.S.: I have created a [fix / extension](https://github.com/Gericop/Android-Support-Preference-V7-Fix) to the support preferences-v7 lib's annoying things that you might want to check out.

Comment: You are on point. I've tried so many things in about 2 hours but didn't really think of this. Thanks for the explanation as well, I didn't know the reason why the `android:` prefix is missing sometimes.

Comment: Thanks! saved me lots of time, in fact I would never able to discover it myself :)

Answer (score 1):

Also for radio buttons color add `<item name="colorAccent">#000000</item>` to your style.
Be careful, it's not `android:colorAccent` but `colorAccent`