# Change text color of ListPreference items [Android Pie]

Tags: android, xml, styles, listpreference

i'm tyring to change text color of `ListPreference` items using code below :

**Style.xml :**

```
<style name="PreferencesTheme">
    <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textColorTertiary">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:buttonTint" tools:targetApi="lollipop">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textColorAlertDialogListItem">#ffffff</item>
</style>

  <ListPreference
        android:id="@+id/prefs_duration"
        android:defaultValue="@string/preferences_duration_default"
        android:entries="@array/preferences_duration_entries"
        android:entryValues="@array/preferences_duration_values"
        android:key="@string/preferences_duration_key"
        android:summary="@string/preferences_duration_summary"
        android:theme="@style/PreferencesTheme"
        android:title="@string/preferences_duration_title" />
```

and it's work fine on Android 8.0 and below ,but when i tested it on Android 9.0 it's look like this :

[image]

i want to change text color to white,thanks in advance

Comment: This answer worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46061699/listpreference-text-color