# ListPreference list option text color

Tags: android-layout, android-preferences

I'm trying to style a ListPreference Dialog to suit a dark theme, with the accent color given by my code. However, the text color for each option does not seem to change no matter what attribute I add to it. Is there a way to do this without having to create my own Dialog class?
P.s. I have tried the solution given in this answer: [ListPreference text color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46061699/listpreference-text-color)
And no, it does *not* seem to work.
Here's the required code from styles.xml: (Not the entire code but it's all I need to show)

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="dialogPreferenceStyle">@style/DialogBoxTheme</item>
    <item name="listDividerAlertDialog">@style/DialogBoxTheme</item>
    <item name="alertDialogStyle">@style/DialogBoxTheme</item>
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/DialogBoxTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="DialogBoxTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:layout_centerHorizontal">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_centerVertical">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">320dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">200dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginStart">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginEnd">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/Silver</item>
    <item name="android:textColorTertiary">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/cpWhite</item>
    <item name="textColorAlertDialogListItem">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorAlertDialogListItem">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

(note that I've set colorPrimary and colorAccent to vary with the theme)

Here's the output that it gives:
[ListPreference Dialog appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huX2N.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:
I forgot to add the attribute

```
<item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/DialogBoxTheme</item>
```

to the AppTheme in styles.xml.