# How to replace radio button with image in List Preference Android

Tags: android, listpreference

I have following Preference List.

```
    <ListPreference
        android:key="@string/settings_key_keyboard_theme_key"           
        android:title="@string/select_skin"
        android:entries="@array/select_keyboard_skin"
        android:entryValues="@array/the_value_of_keyboard_skin"
        android:dialogTitle="@string/select_skin"
        android:defaultValue="@string/settings_default_keyboard_theme_key" />

  <string-array name="select_keyboard_skin">        
    <item>White</item>
    <item>Black</item>
    <item>Wood</item>        
    <item>Beige</item>
    <item>Leather</item>
    <item>Purple</item>
    <item>Blackberry</item>
   </string-array>
```

I want to replace **Radio button** of some item with **Image Icon**..So for example it may be like this:

```
If(Item == White || Black || Wood){
(RadioButton).SetVisbility(Invisible)
(ImageButton).SetVisibility(Visible)
}
```

I am new in List Preference Activity. Please give some suggestions?

Comment: This link may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460715/how-to-customize-list-preference-radio-button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to extend `ListPreference` and override `onPrepareDialogBuilder(Builder)` and `OnCreateDialogView()`
see this: [Ho to customize list preference radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460715/how-to-customize-list-preference-radio-button)