# How to know the default android att of title and CheckedTextView in Dialog?

Tags: android

I have read the article [How to customize list preference radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460715/how-to-customize-list-preference-radio-button/14790665#14790665)

I use the following xml lyaout to customize my Dialog, I think that most of default UI of android Dialog is very good, I hope to inherit att, and only change font size.

I have find the default att of CheckedTextView is   **android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle".**

Now I hope to find the default android att of both `<TextView  android:id="@+id/dialog_title" ...>` and  `<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"..>,` could you tell me? Thanks!

BTW,  the default style of dialog title of listPreference isn't  style="?android:attr/windowTitleStyle"

BTW,  I can't the same Title effect if I use style="?android:attr/dialogTitle"

a.PNG is the effect of using style="?android:attr/dialogTitle" 
[image: a.png]

b.PNG is the effect of default dialog title of ListPreference
[image: b.png]

You can try it, use the sample [How to customize list preference radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460715/how-to-customize-list-preference-radio-button/14790665#14790665)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checkMark="@drawable/btn_radio_holo_light"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/list_item_minheight"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_item_paddingLeft"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_item_paddingLeft" />



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:textColor="@color/title_color"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@color/divider_color" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**To Vikram:**

1. android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light" don't work under API 9, how can I set color value for android:textColor? BTW, android:textColor="#ff4d4dff" is wrong.
2. android:listSelector="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" don't work under API 9, how can I setfor API 9? At present, I use  android:background="@android:color/white". BTW, the default background of API 9 is black.
3. I have to add android:background="@android:color/white" for LinearLayout android:id="@+id/title_template", because the default background of API 9 is black.

Modified For API 9

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parentPanel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dip"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dip"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/topPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/title_template"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
            android:minHeight="64dip"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dip"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dip">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/dialog_title"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"                
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <View android:id="@+id/titleDivider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />
        <!-- If the client uses a customTitle, it will be added here. -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/contentPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:minHeight="64dp">

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"  
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: For TextView : `<TextView android:id="@android:id/title" style="?android:attr/windowTitleStyle" ... />` and for ListView : `<ListView android:id="@android:id/list" style="?attr/preferenceListStyle" .../>. Try and let me know whether it works.

Comment: Thanks! but style="?android:attr/windowTitleStyle"  is not the default style of dialog title of listPreference

Comment: I think it is  style="?attr/preferenceFragmentStyle"/ for listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can base your dialog layout on android's:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parentPanel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dip"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dip"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/topPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/title_template"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
            android:minHeight="64dip"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dip"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dip">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/alertTitle"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <View android:id="@+id/titleDivider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />
        <!-- If the client uses a customTitle, it will be added here. -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/contentPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:minHeight="64dp">

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:listSelector="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Using this layout, you can customize your dialog the way you want:

Regular(just like default):

[image]

Smaller text size:

[image]

Different text color and divider color:

[image]

To customize, change the `text_size` attribute of `TextView` with id `alertTitle`. You can also change the `textColor`.

To change the divider color/width, look at the `View` right beneath the `TextView`.

**Edit:**

I'll try and address the three points you have mentioned:

> #1. android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light" don't work under API 9, how can I set color value for android:textColor? BTW, android:textColor="#ff4d4dff" is wrong.

Correct: `#ff4d4dff` is not `holo_blue_light`. Try using `#ff33b5e5`.

> #2. android:listSelector="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" don't work under API 9, how can I setfor API 9? At present, I use android:background="@android:color/white". BTW, the default background of API 9 is black.

For API 9, you can use `?selectableItemBackground` from the support-v7 appcompat library. If you are already using this support library, change `android:listSelector="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` to `android:listSelector="?attr/selectableItemBackground"`. To know why we're doing this, see this answer: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19714682/android-apply-selectableitembackground-in-xml-with-support-v7).

But if you are not using this library, or don't wish to include this library for only one drawable, you can build `selectableItemBackground` based on API 17 on your own.

I have assembled the necessary resources for this. Download this zipped folder: [Link](http://we.tl/hJXLLLQRtW). In the folder, you will find `drawable-XXXX` folders. Copy the stuff from these to respective drawable folders in your project. How to use the drawable:

```
android:listSelector="@drawable/item_background_holo_light"
```

> #3. I have to add android:background="@android:color/white" for LinearLayout android:id="@+id/title_template", because the default background of API 9 is black.

Yes, this looks okay to me.

Comment: To Vikram: Thanks! Your code works well in API 17, but I have to modify code for API 9, I havn't tested the code undr other APIs, I don't know if your code can work well under other APIs. I have updated my question, would you please see the snippet "To Vikram" in my question? Thanks again

Comment: @HelloCW You are very welcome. I have added an `Edit` section to my answer above. If you have any more questions, please leave a comment here.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually check there `style attributes` in the android [developers website](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/ListPreference.html). You can look at the `XML attribute` for the default style used in it.

Since `ListPreference` inherits from `DialogPreference` they will have the same title style which is `?android:attr/dialogTitle` as stated in the [website](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/DialogPreference.html).

For the `ListView` since you are using the default `id` of it then you can just call

`?android:attr/listViewStyle` for the default `ListView` style.

If you are looking for other class that use default style then developer website is the place to go and look.

**EDIT:**

Use the default style of android window title from **HOLO**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dialog_title"
    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.DialogWindowTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="adsdasdasdasd" />
```

Comment: Thanks!

But I can't the same Title effect if I use style="?android:attr/dialogTitle"  

https://www.dropbox.com/s/31vbjg39xq1ag5o/a.PNG is effect of using style="?android:attr/dialogTitle" 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xekgmh0dbocc5yi/b.PNG is effect of default dialog title of ListPreference


You can try it, use the sample http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460715/how-to-customize-list-preference-radio-button/14790665#14790665

Comment: @HelloCW now that varies on what theme you are using, in the picture it is a light theme you should use the light theme title style from HOLO

Comment: Thanks! How can I apply the light theme to my dialog title android:id="@+id/dialog_title"

Comment: Thanks!
I get the error when I use style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.DialogWindowTitle"

@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.DialogWindowTitle requires API level 13 (current min is 8).
I try to use TextAppearance.DialogWindowTitle and TextAppearance.Theme.Dialog, but I can't get the same UI effect.

Comment: @HelloCW That is the only way I can find, ya those wont work, only in HOLO

Comment: @HelloCW what api are you running those images?

Comment: The API I'm running is 17

Comment: And more, it seems that Android system can adjust title style automacically by different API.

Comment: Thanks! I think I was in an error way, I should set style for the customize dialog,  could you tell me how to set style for the dialog?

Comment: The following code don't work, the error is the style is not public.   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    style="@android:style/AlertDialog"
     >

Comment: @HelloCW I think you cant just use a full layout style of the dialog, why not just create a layout for dialog itself dont use any of the default style. just create the style of your own.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59702/discussion-between-hellocw-and-rod-algonquin).