# The color of radio buttons of ListPrference has been changed to that of the background of the dialog

Tags: java, android, xml

The buttons of my Listpreference have been concealed by the background of the dialog box which is white. I'm pretty sure changing the color of the button has to do with a style element, and I just can't figure out which one it is. How do I change the color of either the radio buttons or the background of the dialog?

Comment: Have you recently updated the version of support library your're using? `Theme.AppCompat` style from support library v7 now includes some Material Design features, one of which is Color palette theme attributes in the `Theme.AppCompat` themes. Now to customize the theme's base colors you use attributes such as `android:colorPrimary`, `android:colorPrimaryDark` or `android:colorAccent`.

Comment: @michal.z Yes, I did. But which specifically is for the radio buttons?

Comment: Well, lately I have a problem with color of background of checkbox on my Preference and it was possible to change it by using `android:colorAccent` attribute. Why not try that? :)

Comment: @michal.z colorAccent will change the color of the selection. Not of outer circle. In my case, the outer circle itself is not visible.

Comment: From what I can see it's not possible to customize dialog opened by `ListPreference` in further way through XML. Only `android:colorAccent` works. Maybe this link can help you [Customize ListPreference Dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460715/how-to-customize-list-preference-radio-button).

Comment: @michal.z, yes, thank you! I've already checked that out.

Comment: If you only need to change from white to black and using AppCompat  you can try to derive alertDialogTheme for your settings activity from Base.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog to Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog (or viceversa)