# Why does my listPreference dialog look different?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, listpreference, android-settings

I looked at several tutorials and all their listPreference dialogs look like this.

[listPreference Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaYaE.png)

but my dialog looks like this

[my dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODjM1.png)

Any ideas why my dialog looks different? I reviewed the tutorials and my xml code looks the same as theirs.

Here is my pref_general.xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
  <!-- NOTE: EditTextPreference accepts EditText attributes. -->
<!-- NOTE: EditTextPreference's summary should be set to its value by the activity code. -->
<EditTextPreference
    android:key="@string/pref_location_key"
    android:title="@string/pref_title_location"
    android:defaultValue="@string/pref_location_default"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:capitalize="words"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:maxLines="1" />

<!-- NOTE: ListPreference's summary should be set to its value by the activity code. -->
<ListPreference
    android:title="@string/pref_temperature_units_title"
    android:key="@string/pref_temperature_units_key"
    android:defaultValue="@string/pref_units_metric"
    android:entryValues="@array/pref_temperature_unit_values"
    android:entries="@array/pref_temperature_units"
    />
```

and part of the activity code

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity
    implements Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Add 'general' preferences, defined in the XML file
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);

    // For all preferences, attach an OnPreferenceChangeListener so the UI summary can be
    // updated when the preference changes.
    bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_location_key)));
    bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_temperature_units_key)));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are testing in lollipop device. if you test below lollipop devices, it will look like first one.You can customize it like this '[How to customize list preference radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460715/how-to-customize-list-preference-radio-button)'